# When receiving data about a video through YouTube Oembed, I get a 403 error

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

When we access the YouTube oEmbed service from our server, we receive the following response:
**403.** That’s an error.

Your client does not have permission to get URL `/oembed` from this server.  That’s all we know.

There is no such problem on our other servers, why is this happening?
[youtube-iframe-api](/questions/tagged/youtube-iframe-api)

Link for test: https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlrvzLRgzdc&scheme=https